# How to order unit test execution from Gradle?

Tags: gradle, junit

Is there any way to specify the order of the unit tests classes run by a Gradle [Test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) task?

I'd like to get some known longer-running tests at either the front or the back of the list, but don't know if it's possible without splitting my tests' execution between multiple tasks.

Running JUnit 4.12 and Gradle 4.5.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the answer is that Gradle is just starting JUnit, and so you have to use the JUnit ordering mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle simply delegates execution to the JUnit runner.

So if you want specific test class ordering, you will need to create a `Suite` and specify the test classes in the order you want, see [the JUnit documentation](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/aggregating-tests-in-suites) for this.

Now, given the flexibility of Gradle in terms of having different source roots, I would strongly recommend doing the separation at the Gradle level, by create extra test source roots, test task and the like. This will allow you to effectively control when these long running tests are run in a standard `build` execution, but also to skip them or run these only when desired. The ordering at the JUnit level will not give that flexibility without much more tweaking. See [the Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:defining_new_source_sets) on adding source sets.